# Protractor (e2e Testing) : While testing complex e2e scenarios, should we write the logic to get the output or the output should be hardcoded?

Tags: testing, protractor, functional-testing

I am writing test for a website editor( tool to edit the website), where there is functionality to see the parent list of the selected element. So for example, if we select a span, then select parent functionality will show all the parents (till body) of the selected span.

Now while writing the e2e test cases to check whether the parent list is correctly displayed or not, should I calculate the parents of that element by writing a logic (a function which could be used for other elements as well) or the parents of the selected element should be hard coded? (which would be a lot of effort to test various elements)

If you need any clarity with the question, then please feel free to ask

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means an expert at Protractor, but have been using it for about half a  year.

It is always best to abstract as much of your code as possible, including writing the logic to automate your input values (or in your case "the parents of the selected element").

I'm not sure how your select parent function works, but I'd suggest a function that checks each parent element until there are no more elements to be checked meanwhile assuring each parent element is the desired element.

You can also write a simple recursive function that starts off at the root element and then digs until it hits your specified element, then trace your way back.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the guy who is writing the testcase is duplicating the logic of selecting parent in the specs.

There might be bug in the logic for select parent he has written. So, it kind of becomes complex as he wanted to test the select parent logic and he wrote his own select parent logic to verify it.
Now it becomes a scenario where we are comparing two different algorithms for select parent computation. So, there is no true value to compare to.